# How to prove $\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}$ is bigger than $\sqrt{15}-\sqrt{13}$

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, proof-explanation, radicals, number-comparison

Although I can determine using a calculator that $\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}$ is larger than $\sqrt{15}-\sqrt{13}$, how would I go about proving that? My teacher gave us a hint which was to use the difference of two squares identity $(a^2-b^2) = (a-b)\cdot(a+b)$, but I don't see how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $5 - 3 = 15 - 13$. Now use the hint.

Comment: Square both sides.

Comment: Cute hint.  $2 = 5-3 = 15-13=(\sqrt{15} - \sqrt{13})(\sqrt{15} + \sqrt{13}) = (\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{3})(\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{3})$.  How do $\sqrt{15} + \sqrt{13}$ and $\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{3}$ compare?

Comment: Note also that $3 < 2^2 < 5$ and $3^2 < 13 < 15 < 4^2$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that $$\sqrt { 5 } -\sqrt { 3 } =\frac { \left( \sqrt { 5 } -\sqrt { 3 }  \right) \left( \sqrt { 5 } +\sqrt { 3 }  \right)  }{ \sqrt { 5 } +\sqrt { 3 }  } =\frac { 2 }{ \sqrt { 5 } +\sqrt { 3 }  } ,\\ \quad \sqrt { 15 } -\sqrt { 13 } =\frac { \left( \sqrt { 15 } -\sqrt { 13 }  \right) \left( \sqrt { 15 } +\sqrt { 13 }  \right)  }{ \sqrt { 15 } +\sqrt { 13 }  } =\frac { 2 }{ \sqrt { 15 } +\sqrt { 13 }  } \\ $$

$$\frac { 2 }{ \sqrt { 5 } +\sqrt { 3 }  } >\quad \frac { 2 }{ \sqrt { 15 } +\sqrt { 13 }  } $$

Comment: I've gotten to this by using the hint, but how does this result in proving the original claim? I've gone from this step to showing that √5+√3 < √15+√13. Is that enough to prove the opposite that √5-√3 > √15-√13?

Comment: yes, i edited above these expressions are equal

Comment: The new claim you have to show is much easier! Note that $\sqrt 5 < \sqrt 15$ and $\sqrt 3 < \sqrt 13$.

Comment: No, the whole point is that it's obvious that $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{3}} > \frac{2}{\sqrt{15} + \sqrt{13}}$, but the LHS is *equal* to $\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{3}$ and the RHS is $\sqrt{15} - \sqrt{13}$.

Comment: Ohh okay I understand it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence for any fixed $h>0$ the function
$$\Delta_h(x) = f(x+h)-f(x) $$
is a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 6):

It amounts to proving $\;\sqrt 5+\sqrt{13}>\sqrt 3+\sqrt{15}$.

As everyone is positive, you can compare the squares:
$$(\sqrt 5+\sqrt{13})^2=18+2\sqrt{65}\quad\text{vs}\quad (\sqrt 3+\sqrt{15})^2=18+2\sqrt{45}.$$
Indeed $\;65>45$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}>\sqrt{15}-\sqrt{13}$$
multiply by $(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{13})$
$$(5-3)(\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{13})>(15-13)(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3})$$
or
$$\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{13}>\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle{\,\sqrt{\,{a + 2}\,}\, - \,\sqrt{\,{a}\,}\, =
{2 \over \,\sqrt{\,{a + 2}\,}\, + \,\sqrt{\,{a}\,}\,}}$ is a '$\underline{decreasing}$' function of $\displaystyle{a \geq 0}$. Namely,
$$
\,\sqrt{\,{3 + 2}\,}\, - \,\sqrt{\,{3}\,}\, >
\,\sqrt{\,{13 + 2}\,}\, - \,\sqrt{\,{13}\,}\,
$$

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that $\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{5}>\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{3}$, which is Karamata

because $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is concave function and $(15,3)\succ(13,5)$.

Comment: Karamatas Inequality is, in general, a pretty heavy tool to hit this problem with... Special cases of the theorem would more than likely do the job just as well. This just feels a little outside the scope of the OP's knowledge base

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen I think  Karamata is an obvious easy fact. Much more easier than first solution.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   (\sqrt 5 - \sqrt 3)(\sqrt 5 + \sqrt 3)
   &= (\sqrt{15} - \sqrt{13})(\sqrt{15} + \sqrt{13}) = 2
\\ 
   \dfrac{\sqrt 5 - \sqrt 3}{\sqrt{15} - \sqrt{13}}
   &= \dfrac{\sqrt{15} + \sqrt{13}}{\sqrt 5 + \sqrt 3} > 1
\\ 
   \sqrt 5 - \sqrt 3 &> \sqrt{15} - \sqrt{13}
\end{align}

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio - It took me a minute to figure out what you were talking about. My answer is because I have a slight perception disorder and I put my addendum in the wrong place.